# Inequality regarding positive definite matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $Y$ be a positive semi definite $n \times n$ matrix with minimal eigevalue $b \in \mathbb R_{>0}$.
Let $y=(y_1, \ldots ,y_n) \in \mathbb R^n$ and suppose $y_i>a$ for all $i$. Let $x=(x_1, x_2, \ldots ,x_n) \in \mathbb Z^n$. Can anybody help me see why the estimate
$$
x^T Y x + x^T y  \geq b x^T x + (a, a , \ldots, a) \cdot x
$$
holds?

I found this estimate on page 6 (Section 2, Lemma 3) in the following notes: [https://web.math.princeton.edu/~gunning/theta2/A](https://web.math.princeton.edu/%7Egunning/theta2/A)  and I would like to understand why it is true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First observe that $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $Y$ if and only if $\lambda - b$ is an eigenvalue of $Y - bI$.

Proof: If $Yv = \lambda v$, then $(Y - bI)v = Yv - bv = \lambda v - bv = (\lambda - b)v$. Conversely, if $(Y - bI)v = (\lambda - b)v$ then $Yv - bv = \lambda v - bv$, so $Yv = \lambda v$. $\square$

Therefore, the minimum eigenvalue of $Y - bI$ is zero, so $Y - bI$ is positive semidefinite. Therefore $x^T(Y - bI)x \geq 0$, so $x^TYx \geq bx^Tx$.

For the rest of the inequality, **I'm assuming that the $x_i$ are nonnegative**. In that case, simply note that $y_i > a$ implies $x_i y_i \geq x_i a$. Summing both sides from $i=1$ to $n$ gives $\sum x_i y_i \geq \sum x_i a$, which is equivalent to $x^T y \geq (a,a,\ldots,a) \cdot x$.

---

If the $x_i$ can be negative, then the inequality is not true. For a counterexample, let $Y = I$, $b = 1$, $x = (-1, -1, \ldots, -1)$, $y = (1,1,\ldots,1)$, and $a=0$. Then:

$$\begin{aligned}
x^T Y x &= x^T x = n \\
x^T y = -n \\
bx^T x = n \\
(a,a,\ldots,a)\cdot x = 0
\end{aligned}$$
so the asserted inequality would imply that $n - n \geq n + 0$, or $0 \geq n$, which is false.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Indeed, the problem I also faced was if the $x_i$'s are negative. However, in the reference I gave , the $x_i$'s could be negative. Do you know a way to salvage the situation ?

Comment: @dekimashita I think we need $x_i y_i \geq x_i a$ for $i = 1,2,\ldots n$. This is equivalent to $x_i(y_i - a) \geq 0$. We know that $y_i - a > 0$, so the only way $x_i(y_i - a) \geq 0$ can be true is if $x_i \geq 0$.

Comment: @dekimashita I found a counterexample assuming $x_i$ is allowed to be negative. See the updated answer.